# Perl add colon in 000000000000

Tags: perl

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$macaddress = "000000000000";

print "$macaddress\n"; # Now how to make it 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

How to make it 00:00:00:00:00:00?

[image]

Comment: Why? What will happen if im code in root mode?

Comment: To paraphrase [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/16179): you can break stuff badly.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, Now I know what will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
print join ( ":", $macaddress =~ m/(\d{2})/g );
```

We use a regular expression match on "two digits". We repeat it, so the match returns a list of elements that are each two digits. And then `join` it on `:`.

However, if you're handling hexadecimal numbers, that won't work - you'll need to handle letters as well:

```
my $macaddress = "c0ffeedeAD02";
print join ( ":", lc($macaddress) =~ m/([0-9a-f]{2})/gi );
```

Which will print:

```
c0:ff:ee:de:ad:02
```

(the `lc` lowercases everything).

Note - this technique matches *any* paired digits, and ignores anything else. So you can quite happily do it with:

```
$macaddress = "c0-ff-ee-de-AD-02";
$macaddress = "c0:ff:ee:de:AD:02";
$macaddress = "c0XffJee*de&AD!02";
```

It's joining with a specified delimiter. You can use another (or none):

```
$macaddress = "c0XffJee*de&AD!02";
print join ( "", lc($macaddress) =~ m/([0-9a-f]{2})/gi );
#still prints: c0ffeedead02
```

Comment: How about removing colon in 00:00:00:00:00:00?

Comment: `@addr = split(':', $str); print @addr;` will remove the colon.

Comment: You don't even need to do that - the above matches pairs of hex digits. So ignores ":" in the first place ;). `print join ( "", lc($macaddress) =~ m/([0-9a-f]{2})/gi );` will take any sequence of (paired numbers) with any delimiter. (Omit the `":"` in the join and it'll print without the delimiter)

Comment: @serenesat: Problem in removing colon, 00:00:00:00:00:00 -> 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: @JeromeLaliag No, this will not be the output. Check syntax in your program.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of code with removing colons.

Comment: See the last code block in my answer. - do exactly the same, just don't `join` with `:`.

Comment: print split(':', "$macaddress"); How can I use it in variables?

Comment: `my $newvar =  split(':', $macaddress);`

Comment: I try to use it in varialbles and splitting this `$macaddress = "a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6";` the result is only number 6.

Comment: Oh, yeah. that'd need a `join`. But `my $newvar =  join ( "", lc($macaddress) =~ m/([0-9a-f]{2})/gi );`  will work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is substitution for to do it

```
my $macaddress = "000000000000"; 
$macaddress =~ s/(?<=\d{2})(\d{2})/:$1/g;
print $macaddress;
```

If you want to separate the any two characters use this

```
~s/(?<=..)(..)/:$1/g;
```

Thank you @glenn jackman :)

Comment: To avoid having to chop: `$macaddress =~ s/(?<=..)(..)/:$1/g`

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you for your useful comment post edited :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr):

```
for (my $pos = 2; $pos < length $macaddress; $pos += 3) {
    substr $macaddress, $pos, 0, ':';
}
```